# BootComplete is not working in android 4.4 (app with no activity)

Tags: android

I am having android application which is having only background service. Service needs to run on boot complete. I declared receiver in manifest file. It is perfectly running in android 4.0 but not able to run in 4.4. Don't know Why ?

Is there any dependency that we should run app at least once to capture boot event ?

Answer (score 1):

Your app needs to be started at least one time. This is necessary for the receiver to register and start responding to `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`.

As far as I know there is no difference between how 4.0 and 4.4 handling the on boot completed. Maybe you can create an Activity that launches the service the first time. You can make this a background Activity.